# How to properly escape attribute values in css/js attribute selector [attr=value]?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, selectors-api

How should I escape attributes in the css/js attibute selector `[attr=value]`?

Specifically, is this correct?

```
document.querySelector('input[name="test[33]"]')
```

I'm looking for the "standard way" of doing this, if any, because I don't want Sizzle using a heavy-to-execute fallback function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that is one correct approach. The [Selectors Level 3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) states the following:

> Attribute values must be CSS identifiers or strings.

The example in your question uses a string as the attribute value. An "identifier" is defined as follows:

> In CSS, identifiers... can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code...

So following that, it is also legal to escape the special characters and omit the quotes:

```
document.querySelector('input[name=test\\[33\\]]')
```

Comment: @JamesAllardice is there any function (user-defined) to escape values? `document.querySelector('[name="' + escapeattr(value) + '"]')` thanks

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer - Not that I know of, but you don't need to escape if you enclose the value in quotes, which is what I always do.

Comment: There is currently CSS.escape as a working draft for browsers for this solution without quotes.

Comment: [`CSS.escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape) is the recommended way of solving this and is supported by all modern browsers. Mathias Bynens has a [polyfill](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/CSS.escape/blob/master/css.escape.js) also.

Answer (score 3):

Use [CSS.escape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape_static) . One benefit of using this is that it works with variables, not just string literals:

```js
el = document.querySelector('input[name="' + CSS.escape(name) + '"]');
```

It's supported in all modern browsers ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_css_escape_static)).

Comment: This needs to be the top answer.

Answer (score -2):

use  apo     next level  backslash+apo     next level  ThreeBackslash+apo

```
$('mycard:has(\' mydiv:contains(\\\'Im a Hero\\\')\')')
```

CSS.escape will just create neutral text and you probably want to create nested selectors

sorry  it also does not work correctly   try mix quotes and apos