# CSS img[src="..."] not being applied

Tags: css

At [this page](http://staging.orsgroup.com.au/our-services-2/training-services-3/), I have the image

[image]

which is @ http://www.orsgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/MH-Logo.png

The page above has [this stylesheet](http://staging.orsgroup.com.au/wp-content/themes/nevada-child/style.css?ver=1.8.5), which contains:

```
img[src='http://www.orsgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/MH-Logo.png'] {
    width: 103px;
    height: 192px;  
}
```

However, the image is not being set to `width: 103px` or `height: 192px`, in fact, the CSS rule is not being applied at all.

I can't work out why - can you? Thanks.

**Update**: I've added a class so that the image tag is now:

```
<img class="alignright MHlogo" alt="MH Logo" src="http://www.orsgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/MH-Logo.png" width="103" height="192">
```

and CSS:

```
.MHlogo {
    width: 103px;
    height: 192px;      
}
```

But `.MHLogo` is not being applied?

**Update2**: I commented out

```
img {
    width:auto;
    max-width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    box-shadow: #000 0em 0em 0em !important;
}
```

and `.MHLogo` is now being applied.

Comment: Create a JS Fiddle of it, that will help us to identify the problem.

Comment: Have you tried removing `media` parameter?

Comment: cant you use   

#sitelogo{width: 103px;
    height: 192px;  
}
 ...?

Comment: Why you have chosen such a lengthy way to style? Apply a class to your image and style it in css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist on making it by href, you need to escape it. Something like:

```css
img[src="http\:\/\/www\.orsgroup\.com\.au\/wp-content\/uploads\/2012\/11\/MH-Logo\.png"] {
    width: 103px;
    height: 192px;  
}
```

```html
<img class="alignright" alt="MH Logo" 
  src="http://www.orsgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/MH-Logo.png"
  width="103" height="192">
```

The way I generated this string, is by opening the console in Chrome, and running:

```
CSS.escape("http://www.orsgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/MH-Logo.png");
```

[More about `CSS.escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape)

I agree with everyone here saying that a CSS class is a better way to do it though. I just wanted to make sure I actually answer the specific question.

Comment: Hi Melingy, Thank you for solving this question. I've added an update to my question (I've tried using a class but it is not working).

Comment: I added a 2nd update, and the problem is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to escape attribute value?

Comment: Because special characters have special meaning in CSS, and the parsing isn't good enough to detect string boundaries in attribute value. You can have fun checking the [CSS Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors), but there's also a good explanation in this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13988017/146656 which I found to reply to the comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can add width and height in your stylesheet as

```
.alignright {
    width: 103px;
    height: 192px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

width:auto,height:auto property is overriding your required height and width in the style sheet

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
<img class="alignright" alt="MH Logo" src="http://www.orsgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/MH-Logo.png" style="
height: 103px !important;
width: 129px !important;">
```

You can move height and width to css class if it works.

Comment: Inline styling is always a bad idea, as well as `!important`. For debugging purposes it may be useful, but it does not guarantee that moving those properties to the class's css will work. I would change your last statement to something like "if it works there and not on the css class it's because something is overriding those properties elsewhere."