# querySelectorAll doesn't select select boxes with name

Tags: javascript

I have a form that has multiple select boxes and inputs with a array like name.
So I have multiple select boxes with a name personroom[]. I would like to get these using this

```
 var personroom=document.querySelectorAll("input[name='personsroom[]']");

            alert(personroom.length)
```

it gives me null ("0"). But with the same way I can select all input (text) fields. Strange. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please show the HTML. If you are trying to get "select boxes", then why are you using `input` in your call to `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987979/how-to-properly-escape-attribute-values-in-css-js-attribute-selector-attr-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seemed to have been related to the exact target of the selector.
the original selector `"input[name='personsroom[]']"` didn't work but according to OP comments dropping the `input` worked `"[name='personsroom[]']"`

A note on escaping `[]` characters. In this specific case, that was not the issue as the query string used inline single quotes ► `"[name='personsroom[]']"`

Using this `"input[name=personsroom[]]"` , with no single quotes, you need to escape the `[]` like this `"input[name=personsroom\\[\\]]"`

```js
// The below will fail with "Uncaught SyntaxError..." during execution
//var personroom = document.querySelectorAll("[name=personsroom[]]");

//The below works as we are escaping the special characters
var personroom = document.querySelectorAll("[name=personsroom\\[\\]]");
console.log("1.) personroom.length", personroom.length);

//Also, when using inline quotes, you do not need to escape any characters
var personroom = document.querySelectorAll("[name='personsroom[]']");
console.log("2.) personroom.length", personroom.length);
```

```html
<input type='textbox' name='personsroom[]' />
<input type='textbox' name='personsroom[]' />
<input type='textbox' name='personsroom[]' />
<input type='textbox' name='personsroom[]' />
```

Comment: I did it. no results

Comment: @AzerQurbanov Just updated it with code example. If you have different markup can you add it to your question please, maybe it has to do with that?

Comment: @AzerQurbanov With select tags it works just the same. Just replace `input` with `select` or only `document.querySelectorAll("[name='selectpersonsroom\[\]']")` without the tag if needed.

Comment: Can you point to a reference explaining why the backslashes are necessary in this case? I've run your snippet without the backslashes and it works exactly the same way.

Comment: i did it like this document.querySelectorAll("[name='personsroom\[\]']");

Comment: @torazaburo I removed the explanation as I don't know what the correct explanation is. You seem to know the correct explanation though and as I'm in no position to confirm that information please feel free to add it yourself. I have no issue if you would like to do that. Thank you.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083216/css-attribute-selector-for-css-height-style/41136181#41136181

Answer (score 0):

If you are using select boxes, then you are using `<select></select>`, correct? Change `input` to `select` in your query:

```
var personroom=document.querySelectorAll("select[name='personsroom[]']");

        alert(personroom.length)
```

Comment: no this is select. but i have other input tags. it works properly